Best clustering algorithm when needing to use a distance matrix
I have about 1300 arrays that are 28x1 in size which contain numerical data.
They tend to have some parabolic shape (when plotted), but certainly not all of them.
I want to see how many 'different' plots I have, so I figured I need a clustering algorithm.
I looked for the algorithms out there.
The main problem is that in my case, I cannot make a scatter plot because I cannot express my data in terms of 2 variables.
So for this, I needed a distance matrix.
However, I am also not sure if there would be another way to tackle this.
Then, I thought that hierarchical clustering would be a good algorithm to use.
With this distance matrix, I applied the Chebysev distance to cluster.
Now, my question is, what other algorithms beside Hierarchical Clustering can be applied which I can feed my distance matrix to cluster?
And my next question would be how to apply the elbow algorithm to find the 'ideal' number of clusters? I thought that applying the Chebysev distance within a formed cluster to obtain the mean distance within a cluster would be valid. Then, I would want the maximum value per number of clusters. This can be done for any number of clusters, which will be increased in every iteration. This then yields a plot with the mean distance plotted against the number of clusters.
Can someone help me out?
Thanks!
